# Using vector graphics on android

Tags: android, 2d, vector-graphics

I'm currently attempting to make a simple 2D CAD-type viewer app for Android.  Basically the input file contains a bunch of primitives (rectangles, lines, circles, octagons, that type of thing), and the goal is to draw these to the screen at whatever coordinates/sizes they offer.

My initial instinct is to use a Canvas to draw these to, using a quadtree or some similar structure to track which items will show up on the screen at any given time.

Does anyone have any recommendations here for a better way to implement this (my graphics programming experience is minimal, and hence I'm having problems even finding a starting point to Google from)?

Thanks in advance,

-Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very broad question so my answer will only point at classes that you should be looking at.

Extend a surfaceView to be your cadView, that way you'll be all the calculation outside the main thread.

you'll still have to draw on the canvas.
from the canvas you can `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` and use those values for base comparison on your positions.
Canvas have some primitives drawings types like arc, circle, point.
Further you can use Path to draw full figures, line, filling, quadratic, etc.
for backgrounds you can create color drawables and draw it on the canvas.

and that's pretty much it.